# Provider-hosted apps and Atohosted apps for Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-apps

Can you use a Provider-hosted apps and an Autohosted apps for Office 365? How? You write server side code in them, so how can they work with Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use provider hosted apps and autohosted apps with SharePoint Online. They work because your server side code is not hosted on SharePoint - in case of Autohosted apps your code is hosted on Azure web site, in case of provider hosted some provider hosts it. So basically in your SharePoint site you have "link" wrapped in app package which points to external web site. External web site can use some features of SharePoint (for example get its data or use chrome control).

Comment: So if you use Provider-hosted apps or Autohosted apps in SharePoint Server, they also use Azure and som provider to host it? Or is the server-side code just in SharePoint then?

Comment: Autohosted and provider hosted apps differs only in way they are hosted - autohosted are hosted on Azure, provider hosted elsewhere (for example your own IIS). Server side code runs on host.